# Как задать цветную тень у CardView?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, cardview

Есть CardView, который находится в RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/DutyID">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:clickable="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="услуга 1"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/priceText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="center|end"
                android:text="100"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/priceImageView"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#383838"
                android:clickable="false"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/priceText"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ruble" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/moreImageView"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTintMode="add"
                android:clickable="false"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/sas" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

При нажатии на него происходит событие и устанавливается значение в Background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip"  android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Как сделать что бы тень тоже меняла цвет при нажатии?

P.S. @color/colorPrimary=#FF6634

Comment: Из стандартных я такого не встречал, это вам нужно искать что-то нестандартное или делать это через shape. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197892/add-shadow-to-custom-shape-on-android